# How to force mobile Chrome to open URLs instead of searching

Tags: chrome-for-android

I use Chrome for Android.

When I type for example `http://192.168.1.1:8000/` in the address bar, it opens Google with that address as a search query. I need to open the page and am unable to do so.

I tried different variations with and without manually typing `http://` at the beginning and `/` at the end.

I sent a bug report, but since the fix is probably not coming very soon, I need a workaround. Is there any?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to create a bookmark with the needed URL.
Selecting the bookmark will cause Chrome to properly open the page.